# Sqoop import from Oracle to Hive -- ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: No column by the name entity_idfound while importing data

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am using Sqoop import to load data from RDBMS(oracle) to Hive. Without  --map-column-hive option data is loading without any issues but data types are different than expected.
here is the source code 
--map-column-hive 'ae_header_id=bigint,application_id=smallint,entity_id=bigint,event_id=bigint,accounting_date=date,gl_transfer_date=timestamp' \

Source and destination tables have the same column names.

Sqoop version 1.4.6 and Hive 2.1

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I changed script as below and worked fine.

```
--query  'SELECT AE_HEADER_ID  ,
   APPLICATION_ID  ,
   ENTITY_ID  ,
   EVENT_ID  ,
   EVENT_TYPE_CODE  ,
   ACCOUNTING_DATE ,
   GL_TRANSFER_STATUS_CODE  ,
   GL_TRANSFER_DATE 
    FROM  XXCFI_XLA_AE_HEAD_TEST where $CONDITIONS' --split-by ae_header_id --m 1 \
--hive-import \
--hive-database xxcfi \
--hive-table XXCFI_XLA_AE_HEAD_PQ \
--map-column-hive AE_HEADER_ID=BIGINT,APPLICATION_ID=SMALLINT,ENTITY_ID=BIGINT,EVENT_ID=BIGINT,ACCOUNTING_DATE=TIMESTAMP,GL_TRANSFER_DATE=TIMESTAMP \
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the column name on the Source side, as Sqoop considers them as case sensitive, and change their name accordingly.